# nodeenv -p not working in virtualenv

Tags: python, node.js, virtualenv, pyenv

I have successfully installed `pyenv` and created a virtual environment:

```
$ pyenv virtualenv 3.6.3 venv
$ pyenv activate venv
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

All the previous allowed a successfull `nodeenv` install in a Windows 10 Linux Subsystem with Ubuntu.

I then followed some instructions I found on the Internet to correctly install the `nodeenv` setup:

```
$ pyenv deactivate
$ pyenv activate venv
$ nodeenv -p
```

`nodeenv -p` is suppose to tie the `nodeenv virtualenv` to the `pyenv virtualenv`. This works on my job laptop but stopped working on my personal laptop. Heres is the sequence of events:

```
$ pyenv activate server363
$ pyenv-virtualenv: prompt changing will be removed from future release. configure 'export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1' to simulate the behavior.
$ nodeenv -p
 * Install prebuilt node (9.11.1) ..... done.
 * Appending data to /home/fbenavides/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/envs/server363/bin/activate
$ node -v
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
$ node -V
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
$ nodejs -v
The program 'nodejs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ nodejs -V
The program 'nodejs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install nodejs
$ nodeenv -v
Usage: nodeenv [OPTIONS] ENV_DIR

nodeenv: error: You must provide a DEST_DIR or use current python virtualenv
$ nodeenv -V
Usage: nodeenv [OPTIONS] ENV_DIR

nodeenv: error: no such option: -V
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The Windows 10 Linux Subsystem Ubuntu installation uses the `.bashrc` file to store `pyenv` and `nodeenv` settings, which need to be properly setup in order for the `nodeenv -p` command to effectively install the node server and tie it to the pyenv virtualenv setup:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Comment: What should I do in MAC?